# Cannot access $_SESSION variable in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am having a controller for verifying the user as follows:

```
function index()
{
    if($this->input->post('username'))
    {
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $this->mstudents->verifyUser($username,$password);
        if(@$_SESSION['sutdentUsername']!=""){
        echo "success";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }

}
```

This function is called by ajax in a view as follows:

```
$.post('<?PHP echo base_url();?>account/login/',{username:$("#username").val(),password:$("#password").val()},function(data){

        $("#loginButton").button('reset');
        if(data=="success")
        {
            window.location="<?PHP echo base_url();?>account/dashboard";
        }
        });
```

Now the problem is that when i try to access the session variable in dashboard for validation, it gets a blank $_SESSION array. What could be the problem?

This is my modal code for verifUser:

```
function verifyUser($username,$password)
{
    $data=array();
    $this->db->where('email',$username);
    $this->db->where('password',$password);
    $this->db->where('status','active');
    $Q=$this->db->get('students');
    if($Q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        $row=$Q->row_array();       
        $_SESSION['sutdentUsername']=$row['email'];

    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['sutdentUsername']="";
    }
}
```

I have this code in code in the constructor of the all the controllers:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION);
```

The directory structure for controllers is like:

CONTROLLERS:
account
  -dashboard
  -login
other controllers goes here...

Comment: have you tried to use the session library in codeigniter?

Comment: what is the output of $Q->num_rows()

Comment: the output is one. In fact it is actually returning "success" which means that the session variable was successfully set. I forgot to mention that dashboard controller lies in a separate directory called accounts.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I am in a notion that native PHP SESSIONS are secure as the codeigniter sessions tends to save data in encrypted cookies.

Comment: no not at all. they use the same PHP provided Session with addition to the encrypted cookies. and in codeigniter it's highly recommended.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan So what changes do you suggest in the above code now...

Comment: just enable the codeigniter session library and load it. then replace it with every php session call. leave the structure as it is.

Comment: I don't see your AJAX call, and I don't see code that populates the $_SESSION variable. And what is sutdent?

Comment: This is like what you don't start PHP session in your code. Did you have call of session_start() function?

Comment: @newman Yes i have it in constructor of every controller. Please see my question carefully :)

Comment: Did you try to replace $_SESSION['sutdentUsername']=""; with $_SESSION['sutdentUsername']="test"; in verifyUser? This would make sure there's nothing wrong in the rest of the code. That the problem really is with reading sessions.

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding may be you should try this:

Depending if you auto-load the session library or not, we will need to include:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');

$session_id = $this->session->userdata('some_name');
```

I hope this is the same what you need.

Answer (score 3):

because you are using native php session you need to start the session first using `session_start();` place it inside `index.php` or you can place it in your `__construct()`